# Is "vez" in Mexico used the same as the present tense "ves" in Spain?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, méxico, idiomático

Is "vez" in Mexico used the same as the present tense "ves" in Spain?  As in, "you see" ... or is this a text shorthand that's become popular for "ves" with Latin American Spanish speakers? As in "Hey vez que pasa asi ?"

It was used by a person from Mexico, living in Mexico, telling me that that is a Mexican thing.

Happened during a text conversation and I brought us "Do you mean 'ves?'" No, she said. It is "vez" in Mexico, like "mira." Which of course would be "ves".

I just wanted some second opinions as if I was missing something.

Comment: This must be just a matter of pronunciation. Where have you seen it?

Comment: I'd say it's just a typo because *vez* and *ves* are homophones in dialects with [neutralización](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Spanish_coronal_fricatives).

Comment: That's wrong in everywhere. Maybe it's just a typo.

Comment: No.  Not a typo.  Was used by a person from Mexico, living in Mexico, telling me that that is a Mexican thing.  Happened during a text conversation and I brought us, "Do you mean 'ves?'" No, she said.  It is "vez" in Mexico, like "mira." Which of course would be "ves." :/ I just wanted some second opinions as if I was missing something.

Comment: *¿Ves que pasa así?* is the correct form. — I can confirm that for no reason *ves* & *vez* must be confused.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt but I think by now it is clear to you that you should not trust that person. He made a mistake and took you for a fool not wanting to recognize he was wrong when you pointed out the right way to write it. It is not a Mexican thing.

Comment: Not everybody in every language speaks or writes correctly. She happens to be wrong. Just don't trust *everything* a native speaker teaches you. You might know better. As we do in English when kids confuse their, there, they're but we know they are wrong. Don't make a fuss out of it.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not correct.

[`"Vez"`](http://dle.rae.es/?id=biPx6YF) is a noun for `"time"`, like `"Once upon a time"` translate to `"Érase una vez"`; or `"Two at a time"` translate into `"Dos a la vez"`.

[`"Ves"`](http://dle.rae.es/?id=baOo6Gz) is the present (indicative) form of the verb `"Ver"` for the second person singular (`"Tú"`/`"You"`). For example, `"Tu ves"` translate into `"You see"`, or `"Ahora lo ves"` translate into `"Now you see it"`.

So it was a mistake of the person you were talking to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is not about the differences between `vez`and `ves`.

Comment: The differences ARE the answer, but I updated it to make it more clear. @VladimirNu